# Have div go under a position fixed nav

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to fix an issue where when I make any divs under my nav it goes to the top left of the page. If I put a padding-bottom on the nav it fixes the issue, but I'm trying to make the page responsive and not have to play around with padding numbers.

https://codepen.io/gmorabito/pen/JjMMdOj

```
nav{
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    width: 95%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;   
    z-index: 9999;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-left:2.5%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: If you're using position:relative on some things, it will not look great by default when you don't use it on some other things, in this case the div there is not goint to adjust itself with regard to your other divs, since the other divs have been told to be relative to eachother, and the new div has not. Same goes with the position:fixed that you're using on your nav.

Comment: What would you recommend @Stoff

Answer (score 1):

make the nav position:static and add 25px to margin-top.  Absolute positioning should be avoided as much as possible.  It takes the element out of the flow of the dom and makes responsive websites much more difficult

Comment: How do I make the nav stay at top though?

Comment: use position:sticky;